# How to get second from UIDatePicke?

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 120, 0, 0);
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

according to my code i set UIDatePicker to present as UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode
how can i get the value as minutes from uidatepicker ?

Comment: Do you want to get seconds or minutes? Subject seems inconsistent with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of seconds that has been selected, do:

```
NSTimeInterval numberOfSeconds = datePicker.countDownDuration;
```

Then you can get minutes by dividing by 60.